# Output redirection at the beginning of line

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file, shell-script

I'm used to specify output redirection on the end of the line like:

```
echo blah > output.txt
```

Both in Windows and *nix.

Recently I'm seeing more and more examples that redirect at the beginning of the line, like:

```
> output.txt echo blah
```

Again, this seems to work both on Windows and *nix.

Is there any advantage to redirect the output at the beginning of a line? Does it behave identically to redirecting at the end of a line or is there some difference? Why are there even the two options?

Answer (score 5):

For such simple examples it does not matter where the redirection happens. It's a choice of coding style here. The [Bash manual states](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> The (...) redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command.

What is a [simple command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Commands.html)?

> A simple command is the kind of command encountered most often. It’s just a sequence of words separated by blanks, terminated by one of the shell’s control operators (see [Definitions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#Definitions)). The first word generally specifies a command to be executed, with the rest of the words being that command’s arguments.

The order of redirection commands matters when there is more than one, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to write `count: 1` to a file.

For Windows, `echo count: 1>file.txt` will write `count :` to the file (without the 1) because the 1 is interpreted to mean stdout. You could use `echo count: 1 >file.txt`, but then there is an unwanted trailing space. Placing the redirection at the front avoids the problem: `>file.txt echo count: 1`.

Not sure, if this also applies to 'nix, but I suspect it does.